# How to pass a query string in the URL with PUT or POST on an array?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to make an update on a list of elements using an angular $resource service:

```
.factory('Elements', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('../api/:type/:id', 
        {   type:'@type', id:'@id' }, 
        {   update: { method: 'PUT' }, 
            updateList: { method: 'PUT', isArray: true }
        });
    }])
```

**1** inside the controller, this function **updates a single object**:

```
element.update({ 'name': name, 'value': value });
```

It sends an HTTP PUT request to the server with this url: `/api/theType/theId?name=theName&value=theValue`. This is working fine.

**2** Now, instead of a single object, this function **updates an array of objects**, using the `updateList` method:

```
elements.updateList({ 'name': name, 'value': value });
```

**the problem:**

In this case, the requested URL is `/api/theType`. But why the query string (`name=theName&value=theValue`) is not here anymore?

**How to pass a query string in the URL when updating an array with PUT?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both calls are probably broken, and you don't know it. In the current state, you're just updating the server with the parameters object instead of the real data.

When passing a single object on non-GET actions, it's passed as the data for update. From the docs:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> ...
>
> - non-GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`

So it is just a misuse of the action method. Send the data object for update after the action parameters, and you're good to go:

```js
element.update({ 'name': name, 'value': value }, dataObject);
```

---

#### Source

[`$resource` on the AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)